# Do I need to change team for my free daily incense to attract a different Galarian bird?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm in the Blanche's Mystic team in Pokemon Go and somehow when I encounter a Galarian legendary bird, it's always an articuno.

**Do I need to change team for my free daily incense to attract a different Galarian bird?** E.g. Galarian Moltres / Zapdos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your team does not affect which Galarian bird will spawn with the daily incense. I am team Mystic, and I have found Galarian Zapdos through this. I have a friend who is team Valor, and they have encountered all three Galarian birds